# How to set ajax response in simple_form select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, simple-form

I have an ajax request responsible for get some cities of a chosen state. So, I have a form using simple_form and two selects, state and city, as follow:

I don't know how to replace the cities of cities select. That's how I did it:

```
Controller ajax method
def by_state
   cities = City.by_state params["state"]
   render :json => { :cities => cities }
end


Form
<%= simple_form_for @store, :html => { :class => 'store-filter' } do |f| %>
  <table align="center" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Store list</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>State:</td>
      <td>
        <%= f.input :state, :collection => State.all, :include_blank => false, :label => false, :input_html => { :id => "state", :name => "state" } %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>City:</td>
      <td>
        <%= f.input :city, :collection => City.find(:all, :conditions => { :state_id => 1 }), :include_blank => false, :label => false, :input_html => { :id => "city", :name => "city" } %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    .
    .
    .

Ajax
$("#state").change(function() {
  var state_id = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "cities/state/"+state_id,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data); //returns Object with Array of Cities
      $("#city").html(data["cities"]); //replaces to nothing city select 
    }
  });
});
```

So, when I choose a state, the city select is replaced by null. Why?
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think there is no need of AJAX. You can Populate one dropdownlist from another dropdownlist. 
Here is lot of useful information : http://forums.asp.net/t/1431726.aspx